# Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u

Tags: ios, automation, automated-tests, appium

Appium version 1.4.13
xcode version 7.2
When i starting my code, i taking error in log. ideviceinstaller is instaled. Help me with this problem.

> Error log: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error:
>   Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u
>   9B2E5BE1-C31B-4484-B14C-73E2554F7887 -i
>   /Users/Ark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ark-bwydkfpusazddvfbasvrcjailpjv/Build/Products/QA-iphoneos/Ark.app

java code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by betbull on 1/29/16.
 */
public class Runing {
public static IOSDriver driver;
    public static AppiumDriver wd;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "IOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone6");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Ark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ark-bwydkfpusazddvfbasvrcjailpjv/Build/Products/QA-iphoneos/Ark.app");
        driver= new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://macappstore.org/ideviceinstaller/ this should help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the ideviceinstaller prior to using Appium to perform automation tests on iOS. Quoting from [here](http://macappstore.org/ideviceinstaller/) the following should help. Try running on your terminal :

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

// Wait for the command to finish.

Run: `brew install ideviceinstaller`

Comment: brew install ideviceinstaller - i did this, see all log :

Comment: Please verify the app path specified by younin the code.